# One Location for all tools in Cloud Vms

Tags: python, cloud, virtual-machine, cloud-storage

I have access to a set of cloud machines. Each of these machine is responsible for specific tasks and has a set of tools responsible for the task.
Now these tools are updated weekly adding new functions. All the tools are implemented on the python language.

The problem is that I need to upload every time my code to all of these machines. I want to have a common place for the tools for all the VMs. How can I do that?

My initial idea is to just mount on every VM a service like dropbox. However, I dont know if this is the correct approach for the problem.

Could you please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to maintain performance then you probably still want to keep the tools on the machines that actually have to use them. In other words whatever you are doing will probably run slower if you have to access some 'off machine' location to get any tool required.

If what you are looking for is a way to more easily manage and distribute your tool updates to multiple machines, you could store all your tools in a repository (like SVN or GIT etc or even a home made one) and have a script on your machines which runs every day (or hour or whatever you require) to update the tools to the latest release.

Ideally you want your update to only include changes since the last update, but most distributed repositories will support this automatically.